# Writing a Stored Procedure for UI testing

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a web application for which I have been loading data manually (Some SQL inserts statements) for testing purposes. So every time I load data with different values. I thought of creating a `Stored Procedure` but even in Stored Procedure whoever is loading the data for testing has to change the values. Not sure if I am thinking the right way.

For instance, this is what I have right now:

```
INSERT INTO DOCUMENT_SET (DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION_ID, MDATA_ATTRB, MDATA_VALUE, CREATED_TIME, LAST_MOD_TIME, ISACTIVE) VALUES 
(212019, 'SOURCE', 'M1', getDate(), getDate(), 1);
```

So I insert above script around 10 times with different values for one transaction. For another transaction, I have to insert this again 10 times with different values.

Now if I create a stored procedure:

```
Create Procedure Transaction
As
Begin
    INSERT INTO esg.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANS_MDATA (DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION_ID, MDATA_ATTRB, MDATA_VALUE, CREATED_TIME, LAST_MOD_TIME, ISACTIVE) VALUES 
(212019, 'SOURCE', 'M1', getDate(), getDate(), 1); 

    9 more times with different values for one transaction
End
```

So for another transaction, someone has to change the values anyways then what is the benefit of writing a procedure in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get sample/dummy data, or to get the SP to work?

Comment: So my main goal is to get sample data for testing purpose for my UI app so for that if I create a SP do you think it would do what I am looking for. I mean it's gonna create the data but for the second time I have to change the data to insert a different data right.

Comment: For dummy data, I've always used the following site. You can set the desired system if you want to include a create table statement as well... it works well and can get you thousands of records in no time at all: https://www.mockaroo.com/

Comment: First of all, when you do 10 inserts in 10 separate INSERT statements, it's not 1 transaction but 10 transactions. But what you want to achieve is not related to transactions at all, you just want to generate test data and not to write 1000 INSERTS but do this in some other way, right?

Comment: Actually transaction means for one service I need 10 properties that need to be inserted and for another again I need 10 inserts but with different set of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stored procedures can accept input parameters.

```
Create Procedure [Transaction]
    @id int, 
    @attrb varchar(10),
    ...
As
Begin
    INSERT INTO esg.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANS_MDATA 
    (DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION_ID, MDATA_ATTRB, MDATA_VALUE, CREATED_TIME, LAST_MOD_TIME, ISACTIVE) 
    VALUES 
    (@id, @attrb, ...);
...
```

Then, when you call the procedure,

```
EXEC [Transaction] @id = 212019, @attrb = 'source', ...
```

Comment: @sepupic That's the OP's name from his question. :)

Comment: Looks like this is what I am looking for. But in case of more than one inserts how can we insert the values?

Comment: @Mike You would make a separate call to the stored procedure for each row of data that you want to insert, changing the input parameters on each call as appropriate.

Comment: Got it. Thank you Joe for answering in such a nice way. I appreciate it.